# Java- Call a method from the command line

Tags: java, command-line, command

I want to be able to use my application through the command line. More specifically the behavior that I want to implement is this one :

If in the command line I enter the command create I want the method `generateMigrationFile` to be called, else if the command I entered was run I want to run my migrations(`SpringApplication.run` method). How can I achieve this?

### My application main class

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //if entered the command run in the command line
        //SpringApplication.run(MigrationsApplication.class, args);

        //if entered the command create in the command line
        MigrationGenerator generator=new MigrationGenerator();
        try {
            generator.generateMigrationFile("TEST");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("There was an error generating the file");
        }
```

I want to call it like :

`migrationsApp run`

`migrationsApp create`

Comment: use arg's and parse them... oversimplistic example `if(args[1].equals("generate")){ /* do generate code */ }else{ SpringApplication.run(MigrationsApplication.class, args); }` or you could do it the other way and go GUI is if the argument gui is passed. There is no difference between a GUI app and a CLI App to the operating system, just a GUI app makes calls to draw a GUI as part of it running a CLI does not, an application is called not it's called from CLI or GUI

Comment: I really never used the command line so the complete command would be java ApplicationName args right? But let´s say I wanted to do like .Net where I use dotnet command. Would it be possible to add the prefix I wanted( by prefix I mean dotnet)

Comment: I will leave an example in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments you supply when executing the command line are passed on to the `args` parameter. So your code would look something like:

```
If (args.length == 0){
  System.exit(-1);
}
if (args[0].equals("run")){
// do run
} else if (args[0].equals("create"){
// do create
}
```

or you could use a switch statement as well.

Comment: using this way I could add a "sub command" for te create method. For example the file name?

Answer (score 1):

You can use system argument and since you are using spring in your project you can use `@Value` annotation for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        @Value("${command}")
        final String command;
        switch(command) {
          case "run":
            SpringApplication.run(MigrationsApplication.class, args);
            break;
          case "create":
             MigrationGenerator generator=new MigrationGenerator();
             try {
                generator.generateMigrationFile("TEST");
             } catch (IOException e) {
               System.out.println("There was an error generating the file");
             }
             break;
          default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Command is Invalid");
        }
}
```

Pass the argument as `--command` in command line. If you are running jar use command
java -jar  --command=run

Comment: What if I want to add a filename to the create command ?

Comment: also can I simplify the command? instead of doing java -jar.... I could only do for example ```applicationName run```

Comment: use @Value annotations inside `create` case and pass the fileName there.
For example 
```
case "create":
   @Value("${file.name}")
  final String fileName;
  // code
```

Answer (score 1):

So this is an example that shows an idea of how it can be implemented but note I'm never checking args at an exact position, useless arguments should not break the application running.

You will also notice in my example if no argument is passed it assume GUI mode, good practice so if people double click on your .JAR it loads in GUI mode. if this was CLI only app then yeah forcing an argument or arguments is fine but if you have a GUI mode use that mode as the default unless overridden by the user.

E.G expected to work
`java -jar MyApp.jar some crap generate` the argument generate is there and it should be honored.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean showGui = true;
        boolean generate = false;

        for (String arg : args){
                if(arg.equals("generate")){
                        showGui = false;
                        generate = true;
                }
        }

        //if entered the command run in the command line
        if(showGui){
                SpringApplication.run(MigrationsApplication.class, args);
        }

        //if entered the command create in the command line
        if(generate){
                MigrationGenerator generator=new MigrationGenerator();
                try {
                    generator.generateMigrationFile("TEST");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("There was an error generating the file");
                }
        }
}
```

I'm using an If because it's a simple demo with only 1 custom argument if you want to support more switch it to a `switch ... case` statement but I would highly recommend that your `run` argument is not supported and by default, it falls to GUI mode